# How to caculate Position Cost Price in given trading list quickly?

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Given a simulated trading list as

```
 lstTrading = {{"Index", "Capitals", "Positons", "Assets", "ClosePrice", "PerAgentCost", "PerTaxCost", "ProfitRate", "ProfitAmout", "DealQuantity", "DealType"}, 
{1, 500000, 0, 500000,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, " "}, 
{2, 500000., 0., 500000., 3.15, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., " "}, 
{3, 436986., 20000., 499986., 3.15, 14.49, 0., 0., -14.49, 20000., "+"}, 
{4, 393506., 33800., 499976., 3.15, 10.,0., 0., -24.49, 13800., "+"}, 
{5, 409485., 28800., 501645., 3.2, 5., 16., 0.33, 1644.51, 5000., "-"}, 
{6, 501244., 0., 501244., 3.19, 21.13, 91.87, 0.25, 1243.51, 28800., "-"}, 
{7, 501244., 0., 501244., 3.18, 0., 0., 0.25, 1243.51, 0., "-"}};
```

or generally show matrix form as

```
lstTrading // TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> Automatic] &
```

[image]

The last column's value represents `doing BUY` when `+` or `doing SELL` when `-` or `doing nothing`. I want append a new column with name `POSITION COST PRICE`, so how to 
caculate the value for each row quickly? Among the columns it has `Assets = Capitals + Positions*ClosePrice` and when `doing BUY or SELL` there be `AgentCost` or `TaxCost` in the rows. There might be different formulas to calculate the result,no matter which shall be ok. Thanks!

Update:
**Definition v1. Caculating Position Cost Price**

$$ Current \space Position \space Cost \space Price =   \frac{\left(\sum buyAmount_i - \sum sellAmount_j\right)}{ latest \space Position} 
$$
where 
$$
buyAmount_i = ClosePrice_i * DealQuantity_i + ( PerAgentCost_i + PerTaxCost_i)
$$
and
$$
sellAmount_j = ClosePrice_j * DealQuantity_j - ( PerAgentCost_j + PerTaxCost_j)
$$

when the Positon was sold out (when positon level became zero), the previous cost shall be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of operations that `Dataset` was made for, even though it is also very possible to do it with lists.

With `Dataset`, we would start by creating the dataset like this:

```
columns = Association @@ Thread[{
      "Index", "Capitals", "Positions", "Assets",
      "ClosePrice", "PerAgentCost", "PerTaxCost",
      "ProfitRate", "ProfitAmout", "DealQuantity",
      "DealType"
      } -> Range[11]];

lstTrading = {
   {1, 500000, 0, 500000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, " "}, {2, 500000., 0., 
    500000., 3.15, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., " "}, {3, 436986., 20000., 
    499986., 3.15, 14.49, 0., 0., -14.49, 20000., "+"}, {4, 393506., 
    33800., 499976., 3.15, 10., 0., 0., -24.49, 13800., "+"}, {5, 
    409485., 28800., 501645., 3.2, 5., 16., 0.33, 1644.51, 5000., 
    "-"}, {6, 501244., 0., 501244., 3.19, 21.13, 91.87, 0.25, 1243.51,
     28800., "-"}, {7, 501244., 0., 501244., 3.18, 0., 0., 0.25, 
    1243.51, 0., "-"}
   };

ds = Dataset[lstTrading];
ds = ds[All, columns](* Rename columns *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can now add a new column like this:

```
ds[All, Append[#, "PositionCost" -> #PerAgentCost + #PerTaxCost] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to do logic that is contingent on one of the other columns, for example, do a different thing depending on whether `DealType` is `+` or `-`, then you do it like this:

```
ds = ds[All, If[
   #DealType == "+",
   Append[#, "PurchasePrice" -> #ClosePrice #Positions],
   Append[#, "PurchasePrice" -> 0]
   ] &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can get your list back like this:

```
Prepend[
 List @@@ Normal[ds],
 Keys@First@Normal[ds]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks!  The command `Dataset` is useful, but how to do accumulating computation over records. I've updated definition the question, Hope that I lve exactly explained what to be computed.

Comment: @Jerry The idea is to create a new columns for buyAmount, sellAmount and latestPosition, then use those to compute currentPositionCostPrice.  Maybe I'll have time later to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,define function to calculate Position Cost Price as

```
fCaculatePosPrice[list_?ListQ] :=
    Module[ {lstBuy, lstSell, lstPosi, posQty, posPrice},
        lstBuy = Select[list, Last[#] == "+" &];
        lstSell = Select[list, Last[#] == "-" &];
        lstPosi = Select[list[[1 ;;, 2]], # > 0 &];
        If[ Length@lstPosi > 0,
            posQty = Last@lstPosi,
            Return[0]
        ];
        posPrice = 
         If[ posQty > 
           0,
             (If[ Length@lstBuy > 0,
                  Total[Times @@@ lstBuy[[1 ;;, {4, 9}]]] + 
                   Total@Flatten@lstBuy[[1 ;;, {5, 6}]],
                  0
              ] - 
             If[ Length@lstSell > 
              0,
                 (Total[Times @@@ lstSell[[1 ;;, {4, 9}]]] - 
                 Total@Flatten@lstSell[[1 ;;, {5, 6}]]),
                 0
             ])/posQty,
             0
         ];
        Return[posPrice];
    ]
```

then apply `fCaculatePosPrice` to each step sub-list-items.

```
(*Pick data from lstTrading*)
lstList = Rest /@ Rest@lstTrading;

(*Group items by Steps*)
lstStep = Partition[lstList, Length@lstList, 1, -1, {}]

(*Apply fCaculatePosPrice*)
lstPPrice = 
 Prepend[Round[fCaculatePosPrice /@ Reverse@lstStep, 0.0001], 
  "PositionCostPrice"]
```

at last, show the result.

```
MapThread[Append, {lstTrading, lstPPrice}] // TableForm
```

$$
\tiny{
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 \text{Index} & \text{Capitals} & \text{Positons} & \text{Assets} &
   \text{ClosePrice} & \text{PerAgentCost} & \text{PerTaxCost} & \text{ProfitRate} &
   \text{ProfitAmout} & \text{DealQuantity} & \text{DealType} & \text{PositionCostPrice}
   \\
 1 & 500000 & 0 & 500000 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &   & 0. \\
 2 & 500000. & 0. & 500000. & 3.15 & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. & 0. &   & 0. \\
 3 & 436986. & 20000. & 499986. & 3.15 & 14.49 & 0. & 0. & -14.49 & 20000. & + &
   3.1507 \\
 4 & 393506. & 33800. & 499976. & 3.15 & 10. & 0. & 0. & -24.49 & 13800. & + &
   3.1507 \\
 5 & 409485. & 28800. & 501645. & 3.2 & 5. & 16. & 0.33 & 1644.51 & 5000. & - &
   3.1429 \\
 6 & 501244. & 0. & 501244. & 3.19 & 21.13 & 91.87 & 0.25 & 1243.51 & 28800. & - &
   -0.0432 \\
 7 & 501244. & 0. & 501244. & 3.18 & 0. & 0. & 0.25 & 1243.51 & 0. & - & -0.0432 \\
\end{array}}
$$